# What Privileges Are Available in Meta Super User?

Tags: support, privileges

Unlike Stack Overflow Meta (and the main Super User site), Super User Meta does not show privileges available to users when hovering over the username. Are there any plans to add this feature, or should it be assumed that users will have the same privileges as in the main Super User site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per-site meta sites such as Super User Meta inherit the rep from the Main site and consequently, will have the same<sup>*</sup> privileges as the main.

<sup>*</sup>*there are certain exceptions - such as tag wikis are pulled from Meta.Stack Overflow and suggested edits are not available, but for the most part the answer holds good.*